# Google Compute Engine MongoDB trouble connecting via Java Driver

Tags: java, mongodb, google-compute-engine

I created a new project and Click to Deploy a MongoDB Compute instance.

I set the primary VM instance to allow HTTP traffic.

Then in eclipse I wrote the following code to determine if I could connect to the MongoDB instance.

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(EXTERNAL_IP);

List<String> dbs = mongoClient.getDatabaseNames();
for(String db : dbs){
    System.out.println(db);
}
```

The EXTERNAL_IP constant is the IP address copied from the list of VM in Compute Engine.

I was getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=[{address=EXTERNAL_IP:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect}}]
```

Then I tried opening port 27017 in the default network on Google Compute and I was able to get through to MongoDb.

Is this the correct thing to do to get a connection?

I have a fear that it would allow anyone to gain access to the database and mess with the information stored within. I assume that I am meant to place my app in  a VM Instance in the same network space on compute engine and connect using the Internal IP.

Comment: What is the value of `EXTERNAL_IP` ? Can it be reached via a ping?

Comment: You definitely don't want to open your MongoDB replica set to the world. If your application is connecting remotely from a fixed/known IP you would want to limit access via firewall and ideally use an encrypted connection (VPN works well for connection to replica set) with authentication enabled on your MongoDB instances. For more information on best practices (including example firewall configs) see the Security section of the MongoDB manual: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/security/. Where is your application running .. on another VM on Google Compute?

Comment: The EXTERNAL_IP can be reached by a ping.

Comment: @Stennie thank you for your comment I will read up on Security. To answer your question: I hope one day to have the app running on a VM on Compute. I understand that in that instance I would be able to use the Internal IP to connect to the MongoDB VW Instance. My coding strength is in Java application development which means that my app will most like start out as a jar executable running on the client pc. Second iteration will be something that can be ran on a web server. For now the fastest way to get code out is to stick with what I know.

Comment: Is this set up just for development purposes, or will you have other users of your desktop app? For development connections to a standalone remote MongoDB server, an SSH tunnel is probably the most convenient way to securely connect without opening your database ports to the world. If you have a deployment that requires connections to multiple nodes (i.e. a replica set or sharded cluster) a VPN would be easier. If you need to allow end users to connect from your application, you would want to create an endpoint/API rather than providing direct access to your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While GCE instances have almost unrestricted access to the internet (SMTP being the big exception), in order to allow incoming connections, the appropriate firewall rule needs to be set up on the network being used, as you well did. You can further fine-tune the access rule by specifying source IP and port for these MongoDB connections, as well as use labels on the VMs, specifying these same labels in the destination part of the firewall rule, further limiting access to only the group of VMs that have that label. And while having you app hosted on the Google Cloud Platform grants you improved performance, it is by no means a prerequisite to use the environment.

Additionally, you can always set up more secure means of connection, such as VPNs, et al.